# I uninstalled LibreOffice via Software Boutique, but there is still LibreOffice item in Menu-Office (Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, lts, ubuntu-mate, software-boutique

I uninstalled LibreOffice via Software Boutique, but there is still LibreOffice item in Menu-Office (Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS).

So, my question is how to remove it from the Menu?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the real installation source.
It maybe installed from Snap or Flatpak. To remove such versions use commands below:

```
snap remove libreoffice
flatpak remove org.libreoffice.LibreOffice
```

For complete removal of deb-packages use command below:

```
sudo apt-get autopurge '*libreoffice*'
```